# Calling functions accross classes causes Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved

Tags: c++, mfc, runtime-error, calling-convention

I have a function that calls another function, which causes the following run-time check failure upon return to the calling function:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function
>   declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared
>   with a different calling convention.

The GridCtrl class:

```
class CNJAGridCtrl : public CWnd
```

The calling function code:

```
LRESULT CNJAGridCtrl::OnUpdateCell(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (!(BOOL)wParam)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (!m_bAllowUpdate)
    {
        return true;
    }

    NJACELLINFO *pDisp = (NJACELLINFO*)lParam;
    NJACELLINFO sDisp;
    sDisp.m_bFormatOnly = TRUE;
    sDisp.m_iColumn = pDisp->m_iColumn;
    sDisp.m_lLine = pDisp->m_lLine;
    GetDimensions(&sDisp);

    sDisp.m_csText = pDisp->m_csText;
    BeginWaitCursor();
    UpdateCell(m_ctlLine.IsCurrentAddLine(), pDisp);//Function call with issue
    m_ctlSheet.InvalidateLine(sDisp.m_lLine, sDisp.m_lLine);
    EndWaitCursor();

    return true;
}
```

The called function class:

```
class CGridProdReport : public CNJAGridCtrl
```

and code:

```
void CGridProdReport::UpdateCell(BOOL bAdd,NJACELLINFO sDisp)
{
//Crashes even without any code
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The compiler is set to use __cdecl across the board.

Comment: There's no need to put the tags in the title.

Comment: How is `void CNJAGridCtrl::UpdateCell` declared?

Comment: virtual void CNJAGridCtrl::UpdateCell(BOOL bAdd, NJACELLINFO sDisp)
{
 //** Virtual Functions - DO NOT DELETE!!!
}

Comment: I think that changing the parameters to &sDisp might have sorted it, but I don't know why...